# I have this code, but is there any way to shorten it so that I don't have to write it every time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, query-string

I think I am repeating the same piece of code each time. Is there any way to shorten this code so that I do not have to rewrite it?

```
router.get('/reports', async (req, res) => {

  let filters = {};
  if (req.query.y) filters['end_year'] = req.query.y.split(',');
  if (req.query.t) filters['topic'] = req.query.t.split(',');
  if (req.query.s) filters['sector'] = req.query.s.split(',');
  if (req.query.r) filters['region'] = req.query.r.split(',');
  if (req.query.src) filters['source'] = req.query.src.split(',');

  const reports = await Report.find(filters);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a mapping object, and iterate through `req`? Something like:

```
const filterMap = {
  y: `end_year`, t: `topic`, s: `sector`,
  r: `region`, src: `source` };
Object.keys(req.query).forEach(k => {
  if (filterMap[k]) {
    filters[filterMap[k]] = req.query[k].split(`,`));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, is create a simple sub function.

```js
const query = {
  y: '2022,2021',
  t: 'C++,C#',
  s: 'Accounts,Sales',
  r: 'South West,North',
  src: 'Bloomberg,MSN'
};

{
  const filters = {};
  const set=(s,d)=>filters[d]=query[s].split(',');
  set('y',   'end_year');
  set('t',   'topic');
  set('s',   'sector');
  set('r',   'region');
  set('src', 'source');

  console.log(filters);
}
```